# Plotting multivariable functions with dependent variables in domain

Tags: pgfplots

Trying to plot a hyperboloid with domain `x^2+y^2 <= 50`. For now I have set the domain to [-5,5], but this yields ugly plots, see below. Any advice on how to get around this? I tried setting the domain in terms of x and y (and x domain in terms of y and vice versa), but to no avail.

Ideally I would like to apply the same solution to the gradient vector field, should there be one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\xdefinecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{220,220,220}
\xdefinecolor{goldenrod}{RGB}{255,223,66}
\xdefinecolor{newblue}{RGB}{57,106,177}
\xdefinecolor{newred}{RGB}{204,37,41}
\xdefinecolor{newgreen}{RGB}{132,186,91}
\xdefinecolor{newpurple}{RGB}{144,103,167}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.5,domain=-5:5]
{(1/100)(50-x^2-y^2)};
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({3*cos(deg(x))},{3*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({4*cos(deg(x))},{4*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({5*cos(deg(x))},{5*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({6*cos(deg(x))},{6*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({7*cos(deg(x))},{7*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[newpurple,double=newpurple,->] plot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (-1,3)
};
\addplot[newblue,double=newblue,->] plot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (7,-1)
};
\addplot[newred,double=newred,->] plot coordinates {
    (7,-1)
    (-1,3)
};
\addplot+[newred,double=newred] plot coordinates {
    (1,2)
};
\addplot[newgreen,double=newgreen] plot coordinates {
    (-3,-6)
    (3,6)
};
\addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
    quiver/u=-x/50,
    quiver/v=-y/50,
    quiver/scale arrows=0.1,
    -stealth,samples=10] {1};          
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: It makes the plot show up incorrectly (x^2+y^2 is allowed to grow to 98, distorting the "heat map"), so no.

Comment: Please always post complete examples (starting from `\documentclass`) instead of snippets. It's no fun to first have to clean up the code (what's `newblue`, `newred`, etc.?) before one can start to work on a solution.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about them! Will update!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `data cs=polar` to provide the equations in polar coordinates. Also, you can use `\foreach` loops to simplify the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3 [
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    opacity=0.5,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=0:7,
    samples=100, samples y=7,
    data cs=polar
] {(50-y^2)};

\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \addplot [domain=0:360,samples=100, data cs=polar] {\i};
}

\draw [purple, ultra thick, ->] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:-1,3);
\draw [blue, ultra thick, ->] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:7,-1);
\draw [red, ultra thick, ->] (axis cs:7,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,3);

\addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
    quiver/u=-cos(x),
    quiver/v=-sin(x),
    quiver/scale arrows=0.1,
    -stealth,samples=10,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=0:sqrt(50),
    data cs=polar] {1};          
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to stick with cartesian coordinates for specifying the function, you can limit the range of the color map using `point meta min=0`, and cover the unwanted bits of the surface plot using `\fill [white] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1) (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=7];` (this requires `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}` or higher).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\xdefinecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{220,220,220}
\xdefinecolor{goldenrod}{RGB}{255,223,66}
\xdefinecolor{newblue}{RGB}{57,106,177}
\xdefinecolor{newred}{RGB}{204,37,41}
\xdefinecolor{newgreen}{RGB}{132,186,91}
\xdefinecolor{newpurple}{RGB}{144,103,167}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.5,domain=-7:7, point meta min=1]
{(50-x^2-y^2)};
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({3*cos(deg(x))},{3*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({4*cos(deg(x))},{4*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({5*cos(deg(x))},{5*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({6*cos(deg(x))},{6*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({7*cos(deg(x))},{7*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[newpurple,double=newpurple,->] plot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (-1,3)
};
\addplot[newblue,double=newblue,->] plot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (7,-1)
};
\addplot[newred,double=newred,->] plot coordinates {
    (7,-1)
    (-1,3)
};
\addplot+[newred,double=newred] plot coordinates {
    (1,2)
};
\addplot[newgreen,double=newgreen] plot coordinates {
    (-3,-6)
    (3,6)
};
\addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
    quiver/u=-x/50,
    quiver/v=-y/50,
    quiver/scale arrows=0.1,
    -stealth,samples=10] {1};

\fill [white] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1) (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=7];         
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, the loop is smart, will implement that! The polar coordinates trick works but leaves a squiggly boundary and kind of obfuscates the math, at least for my untrained eyes. This being my math notes for class, I like being able to go back and see how I plotted things in retrospect.

Comment: @Puffton: I wouldn't call it a "polar coordinates *trick*": for radially symmetric functions, using polar coordinates is much more straightforward. The squiggly boundary appeared because I used a different number of samples for the surface plot and for the line plots. I changed the code now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake! Perfect answer, I will cherry pick both solutions for something that looks good and that I feel comfortable with!